# How to change media url structure for special formats

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to change media url for special formats automaticlly, How can i do it ?

for example :

> (images) site.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/2/sample.jpg
>
> (video) site.com/?vid=sample.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it's not possible, because the url of media library will generate automaticlly with wp_upload_dir url, so we can't change one of them.